# How to update a file's content without reopening it?

Tags: c

I´m currently programming a robot for a University project and we are reading motor and sensor data from files. I am currently using this code for all interactions with the drivers:

```
#include "fileinteraction.h"

void readFromFile(char *path, char *input){
    FILE *openfile = fopen(path, "r");
    fscanf(openfile, "%s", input);
    fclose(openfile);
}

void writeToFile(char *path, char *output){
    FILE *openfile = fopen(path, "w");
    fputs(output, openfile);
    fclose(openfile);
}
```

I don't know how much time it actually takes to open and close files but either way im wondering if I can just keep the files open and read their new content somehow.

Our project is on Linux, specifically on an EV3 with EV3DEV.

Comment: Not related to your question, but seriously: PLEASE never, ever read external data into a buffer in C without limiting the length to the length of the buffer. You already use ´fscanf´ where the length can be limited (you need to pass the length of the array to your function, too. As you use it now, it is identical for the banned ´fgets´ function. I understand you are a beginner, but unfortunately such habits stick very easily. Your teacher should be able to explain the details, otherwise you will find details with a simple search for ´buffer overflow´.

Comment: Now this is related: What do you mean with "new contents"? If the contents is created from the same program, you should have this in a variable. For inter-task/process communication, there are much better ways without regular files, e.g. shared variables/memory or FIFOs, queues, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, I suggest you use `mmap`. Check out https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Using mmap, you map the file content into memory and therefore you can directly manipulate the contents.

Comment: That does not really answer the question, there are ways to do this by standard means. It is also likely beyond the experience level of the asker. Finally, ´mmap´ is not part of the standard.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Since the project is on Linux, using `mmap` seems like a valid approach to me. It's also not terribly difficult to use, there are good instructions to be found in the internets, e.g. here: https://linuxhint.com/using_mmap_function_linux/